# Com Javascript é possível executar automaticamente uma função em outro arquvio a parte?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

Tenho duas páginas separadas:

- A primeira contém um formulário com dois campos `input` do tipo
  `date`, dentre outras informações.
- A segunda página recebe um dado dentre as informações do formulário que
  citei antes, mas não as datas.

A primeira envia esses dados para o *Mongo DB Atlas*. A segunda mostra um desses dados, que é um título em forma de botão. Nessas duas páginas estou usando o *Node.js* também.

Tenho uma função que verifica se a data atual é maior que a data final passada pelo usuário. Se sim, quando esta condição for atendida eu gostaria que esse botão, que por sua vez está na segunda página, ou seja, em um arquivo `html` diferente, fosse desativado automaticamente.

Parece algo avançado para mim e não sei se é possível fazer tal coisa, pois envolve dois arquivos `html` diferentes, aonde um possui os `input` do tipo `date` - e consequentemente é neste arquivo que devo incluir o `script` que faz esta verificação - e outro, onde está o botão que preciso ter desativado quando esta condição - se a data atual for maior que a data final - for verdadeira.

**Em resumo, preciso fazer com que essa função escrita em um arquivo a parte realize uma ação automática em outro arquivo `html` diferente.**

Fiz uma pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/515323/como-comparar-duas-datas-usando-input-date-e-objeto-new-date-no-javascript/515328#515328) e um amigo do SOpt me ajudou a arrumar esta função, porém é só uma função e ainda não resolve este novo desafio que descrevi acima. **Meu maior desafio agora é intercambiar esta função entre dois arquivos.**

Comment: Olá, as informações estão salvas no banco de dados? se sim, no segundo arquivo html não é possível fazer uma consulta ao banco e verificar se a condição para exibir/desabilitar o botão é verdadeira?

Comment: @JhonataDesouza Sim, as informações estão em um banco de dados. Eu ainda não implementei a função por não saber como fazê-la rodar no segundo arquivo. No caso eu suponho que ela deve vir no primeiro arquivo, aonde estão os campos de data. Fiz uma pesquisa e acho que o import e export do javascript podem me ajudar, ainda não sei como mas irei testar.

Answer (score 0):

Só com o frontend, você pode passar as datas para o outro arquivo usando [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), em formato de timestamp. Exemplo:

No primeiro arquivo, você salva no localStorage:

```
var minhaData = new Date();
localStorage.setItem( 'minhaData', minhaData.getTime() );
```

No segundo, você lê a data com:

```
var minhaData = new Date( localStorage.getItem('minhaData') );
```